# cakephp joining two tables

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have two tables.

1.officetypes with fields-id(pk),name,under_id

2.officenames with fields-id(pk),name,office_type_id(fk),underid

I have two models:Officetype .php

```
<?php
class Officetype extends AppModel
{    
  var $hasMany = array('Officename');    
}
?>
```

officename.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model'); 
class Officename extends AppModel 
{ 
    public $name = 'Officename';
    public $belongTo = array('Officetype');

} ?>
```

Now how can i associate two models to make inner join

Comment: Please try to clarify your question - it's very hard to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
$subcategories = $this->Officetype->find('list', array(
            'conditions' => array('Officename.underid' => $office_type_id),
            'recursive' => -1
            ));
```

write fields in fields array in the above query, it will create join by itself as you have defined model relationship in models.